# Trying to fill out PDF getting “Object streams are not supported”

Tags: php, pdf

“FPDF-Merge Error: Object streams are not supported”

I’m using this library: https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm/blob/master/README.md and the default code example.

```
<?php

/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

$fields = array(
    'name'    => 'My name',
    'address' => 'My address',
    'city'    => 'My city',
    'phone'   => 'My phone number'
);

$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Not sure what the error is, or if there is a different library I should be using to fill out PDF forms with PHP.

Comment: That means that your chosen library does not support an option in building pdfs which has been present since PDF 1.5, i.e. since 2003. Therefore, it cannot process pdfs making use of that option.